# How to fix TypeError: Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync is not a function when using office-js in Outlook on the Web

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-dialog-api

I am experimenting with building an m365 add-in for Outlook. I've built a sample app where I want to open a dialog from the Taskpane  and send a message to the dialog from the parent.

I have sideloaded the app and running it locally in Outlook on the Web (Chrome on Windows).
In the manifest file the Mailbox version is set to 1.13.

I followed the official documentation found here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#conditional-messaging-from-parent-page-to-dialog-box).
I am supposed to register my event handler for receiving messages in the dialog with `Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync`.

However when I try to call `addHandlerAsync` to register my event handler for receiving messages I am getting the following error: `TypeError: Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync` is not a function.

In the `taskpane.js` where I want to open the dialog I first call `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("DialogApi", "1.2")` which returns `true`. I am able to open a dialog with `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` but still the addHandlerAsync method is not available.

I've also tried with the preview version of office-js but it did not make a difference.

The Mailbox version 1.13 should be sufficient, the Dialog API 1.2 is supported in Outlook on the Web and the isSetSupported returns true so I don't really know what I am missing here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might have an easier time getting help if you provide concrete snippets of code you have right now (i.e. copy-paste the whole files/functions which might be relevant).